# Error "Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail"

Tags: c#, email, office365

i try to send an email with this code...but i have this error :"Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM"

code:

```
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient()
        {
            Host = "smtp.office365.com",
            Port = 25, //587
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            EnableSsl = true
        };
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod= System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network; 
        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("{mail}", "{password}","{domain}");

        var message = new MailMessage
        {
            From = new MailAddress("{mail}","{display name}",System.Text.Encoding.UTF8),

            Subject = "Test mail",
            IsBodyHtml = false
        };
        message.To.Add("{mail}");

        message.Body = "This is a test mail. ";
        try{
            smtpClient.Send(message);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
        }
```

thanks

Comment: Could you double check the port used and try again? Looks like [Office 365 uses a different port](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/pop-and-imap-email-settings-for-outlook-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353)

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that you are connecting to the SMTP client submission endpoint (smtp.office365.com), which can't be used for direct send. For direct send, use the MX endpoint for your Office 365 tenant, which ends with "mail.protection.outlook.com." So, please let your admin check the MX record. Moreover, please check if the SMTP port is 25/TLS.

Moreover, you can try the following suggestions to check if there is any improvement:

- Remove the account and add it again to check the issue.
- Try using another same tenant account to check the issue.

See [Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_winother/client-was-not-authenticated-to-send-anonymous/d405bcb0-f40c-42fa-b1b2-477597100123) for more information.